# PulseAudio does not load module-tunnel-sink-new

Tags: pulseaudio

I want to create a PulseAudio sink on my laptop that forwards input to a PulseAudio server on another machine by issueing the following command:

```
pacmd load-module module-tunnel-sink-new sink_name=machineB server=machineB.localdomain cookie=/path/to/machineB/pulse_cookie
```

I get no error, but a subsequent `pacmd list-modules` does not show the module-tunnel-sink-new. Also, `pacmd list-sinks` does not show the sink I intended to create with above command.

Does someone have an Idea why that is so or what I could do to get an insight what's going on?